# ResponseEntity in RestController

Tags: rest, spring-restcontroller

i need your help.
I have method for creating entity in RestController, but i can not understand how to use ResponseEntity. I just return ResponseEntity.ok, but it's not correct i think.
I got advice to wrap it into object with data and success fields, but i didn't get it.

```
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @RequestBody Course course) {
    try {
        courseService.add(course);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        log.error("Can not create course", e);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Course is valid");
}

@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> update(@Valid @RequestBody Course course, @PathVariable("id") int id)
        throws ServiceException {
    courseService.update(id, course);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Course is valid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `ResponseEntity<>("Course is valid", HttpStatus.OK)`

For more details and guide : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(course, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```